# get the height of child div after importing into html file

Tags: javascript, html, css, vs-web-site-project

I am trying to create a website with multiple pages, so instead of recreating the toolbar for every page I went ahead a made a separate HTML file for my toolbar along with a CSS file for it.

then I simply import my toolbar into every page this way.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Pink Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/HomeStyles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/Toolbar.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        $("#toolbarHolder").load("toolbar.html");
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="toolbarHolder"></div>

    <div id="welcomeScreen">
      <img id="welcomeScreenImg" src="Images/welcome.jpg" alt="Pink Home">
      <p id="welcomeScreenText">Allow us to help you make your home look better</p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

and as for the CSS file the only thing that kind of stands out is that the toolbar is in a fixed position to stay on of the screen and to let the other items go below it[image]

all works well here but on my other pages I want the toolbar to stay fixed on top of the screen but I want other elements to be placed below it
[image]

I am still importing the HTML file into another div. I've tried to solve this problem by using js, basically what I thought of was to get the height of the toolbarHolder div then give the searchBar a margin-top equal to that. but the toolBarHolder div has a height of 0. this is the code

```
<HTML>
 <head>
  <title>Kitchen</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/Toolbar.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/searchbar.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/kitchen.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/toolbar.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(function(){
     $("#toolbarHolder").load("toolbar.html");
     $("#searchbarHolder").load("searchbar.html");
   });

   $('#toolbarHolder').ready(function() {
     var contentPlacement = $('#toolbar').position().bottom + $('#toolbar').height();
     $('#searchbarHolder').css('margin-top',contentPlacement);
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
   <div id="toolbarHolder"></div>
   <div id="searchbarHolder"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

[image]

I've also tried to get the height of the toolbar itself(when it is imported into the holder) but I get an error which I assume it is because js looks for the element before importing it.

I want to place all of the other items below my toolbar and not behind it, when I start scrolling down the toolbar will stay at the top of the screen and the other content will start going underneath the toolbar then disappear.

Comment: in your question you didn't mention where toolbar and search should be located.. the only thing I read you said toolbar on top of page as fixed position.. so where should be search located ?

Comment: I want to start placing elements below the toolbar, for example, the search bar should be below the toolbar and when you scroll the search bar will disappear but the toolbar will still be in its place.

Comment: for that you should provide your css for both toolbar and search input... in case of scrolling you need javascript.

Comment: Yes, I am using javascript and CSS as mentioned but it isn't working. the toolbar is at the top of the screen but the search bar is going behind it, I want it to go below it, and then when I scroll down it should go below it. this can be done by simply adding a margin-top equal to the height of the toolbar but I can't get the height :(

Comment: as I said before you should provide you css code for search and toolbar in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just give `padding-top: height-of-toolbar` to the body tag in your CSS file.

let's say the height of your toolbar is 55px than,

```css
body{
  padding-top: 55px; /* height of toolbar*/
 }
```

```html
<body>
   <div id="toolbarHolder"></div>
   <div id="searchbarHolder"></div>
 </body>
```

Comment: this won't work as I am setting the height of the toolbar to warp the content, I am not giving it any given height.